# Do Watchers work with Global Mixins in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have searched through the Vue documentation and unless I am blind, I cannot see anything that states that watchers cannot be used on child components to parent components, or in my case, to global mixin properties. However, for some reason, I cannot get mine to work...

I have a global mixin that that is used to lock/unlock the window scrolling. Very simply, I am trying to listen for a change to the `bodyLocked` boolean property on the global mixin from a child component.

For some reason, the watcher does fire on page load, but after that, it does not seem to be listening for changes.

Here is my mixin (it is used globally with `Vue.mixin()`):

```
export default {

    data() {
        return {
            bodyLocked: false
        }
    },

    methods: {

        /**
         * Lock the DOM body to disable scrolling.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        _lockBody() {
            this.bodyLocked = true;
            document.documentElement.classList.add('no-scroll');
        },

        /**
         * Unlock the DOM body to enable scrolling.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        _unlockBody() {
            this.bodyLocked = false;
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('no-scroll');
        }

    }

};
```

Here is an example child component:

```
export default {

    watch: {

        bodyLocked: function(locked) {

            console.log('locked: ' + locked);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use a global mixin the components won't share the same instance of the `bodyLocked` data. So changing it in one component won't change it in the others. Every component will have their own `bodyLocked` value.

An alternative way to do this, instead of using a global mixin, would be to share an object on the Vue prototype. Such an object would be shared between all component instances. It would also give clearer namespacing within the components and should have a lower performance impact than a global mixin.

```js
const locker = Vue.observable({
  locked: false,
  
  lock () {
    locker.locked = true;
    document.documentElement.classList.add('no-scroll');  
  },
  
  unlock () {
    locker.locked = false;
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('no-scroll');
  }
});

Vue.prototype.$bodyLocker = locker;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  watch: {
    '$bodyLocker.locked' (locked) {
      console.log('watcher fired: ' + locked);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.no-scroll {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="$bodyLocker.lock">Lock</button>
  <button @click="$bodyLocker.unlock">Unlock</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very interesting, and exactly the sort of solution I would like to end up with... Is there any documentation on `observable`? i.e. is it enouraged by Vue that we use it? Also, whilst you are there, do you happen to know why I cannot use `_locked` as the property name? I used this before and the watcher didn't fire, but when I removed the underscore, it worked absolutely fine... I wasn't able to find anything in the docs about underscores not being allowed in property names

Comment: Observable docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable. Why you can't use `_` or `$` as a prefix in `data` is explained here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data. Also read the **Detailed Explanation** section here: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Private-property-names-essential for more on the use of those prefixes.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I will play around with this and accept the answer if I am able to get it working correctly

Comment: Are you sure it is okay to put functions in a Vue observable? I assume I just call those functions like so: `this.$bodyLocker.lock()`?

Comment: Also, is there any way to put some sort of watch into ther observable? I would ideally like to `watch` the `locker.locked` value and then update the `no-scroll` class on change of that value. In other words, `lock()` will simply be `locker.locked = true`, and then the watcher will update the necessary class... It just seems cleaner than having the class update and property update in each function. I can update my question if this isn't clear...

Comment: @BenCarey Yes, it's fine to put functions in there. You could jump through hoops to make the function properties non-reactive but it doesn't seem worth it. Yes, you would call them using `this.$bodyLocker.lock()`. No, you can't put a `watch` in there but you could put a `watch` on any one of the components to do it, perhaps the one you create using `new Vue`. So in the example I gave in my answer you could put the class manipulation in the `watch` rather than having console logging.

Comment: I thought that might be the case in terms of the watcher... I'll have a think and come back to you

Comment: I just realised something, why are you using `locker.locked`, and not `this.locked`? Surely `this` refers to the current object?

Comment: The reason I ask is because I am placing my observable in a separate file `observables/VueNoScroll/index.js`, and then using `import VueNoScroll from './observables/VueNoScroll'`. So the contents of `index.js` reads like `export default {...`

Comment: @BenCarey I avoided using `this` to ensure the functions would work even if they aren't invoked with a suitable `this` context. In my example the buttons use `@click="$bodyLocker.lock"`, which would lose the `this` context. I could have written them as `@click="$bodyLocker.lock()"` to fix that, or I could have used `bind` to bind the context on those functions, but I went with a closure instead.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll use `this` as it is suited to my use case

Answer (score 2):

From [Vue's documentation for mixin:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Basics)

> Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for
> Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When
> a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be “mixed”
> into the component’s own options.

When your global mixin is declared, every Vue component in your app will have its own data `locked` with 2 methods `_lockBody` and `_unlockBody` to modify its own `locked` value. I believe you expect the value declared in global mixin is shared between component, but it's not. What you are looking for might be a global state management instead: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

Comment: Yes, I realised this when I added `console.log('mounted')` to the `mounted` hook on the mixin, it was fired multiple times... I am hesitant to use state management as I feel it may be a tad overkill for this particular use case. What do you reckon?

Answer (score 1):

Watchers are meant to watch computed and state properties within the same component. A component is basically an object with a closure, hence what you are intending cannot work.